# R-like way to add a % column to a data frame

Tags: r

I want to add a column that shows me the percentage part of that row compared to the some of the column. (sorry for my bad mathematical english here).

```
> trees['Heigth_%'] <- round((100 / sum(trees$Height) * trees$Height), digits=2)
> head(trees)
  Girth Height Volume Heigth_%
1   8.3     70   10.3     2.97
2   8.6     65   10.3     2.76
3   8.8     63   10.2     2.67
4  10.5     72   16.4     3.06
5  10.7     81   18.8     3.44
6  10.8     83   19.7     3.52
```

This work.
But the question is if this is a good and R-like way?

e.g. Is `sum()` called for each row? Or is R intelligent enough here?

Comment: I would say `sum` is called once. Multiplication of a number for a vector is vectorized in R. It seems a good way of doing this to me. A way to test it could be assigning the `sum(trees$Height)` to a variable and compare execution times....for a much bigger data frame.

Comment: It's a good way, except I wouldn't round the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you question if `sum` is called for every row or is R intelligent enough, you can use trace:

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30)
df['b_%'] = round((100 / sum(df$b) * df$b), digits=2)

trace('sum')
round((100 / sum(df$b) * df$b), digits=2)
untrace('sum')
```

Which shows only one call to the `sum` function. Afterwards, R recognizes that the lengths of `trees$Height` and `sum(trees$Height)` differ and tries to replicate the shorter one until is has the same length as the bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, [Vandenman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38951781/4272484) is much more adequate and precise. What follows is not really worth an answer, but as usual - not readable as a comment.

I have added `prop.table()` and `data.table()` (see [majom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38951964/4272484)) approaches to the timings. With 40k rows `data.table()` is a bit closer to the rest, but still slower (~3 ms to ~3.7 ms), with 400k rows it starts to be comparable, and with 4M rows it is finally faster than the rest:

```
library(microbenchmark)

trees <- data.frame(Height = runif(400000, 9, 11),
                    Heigth_PCT = numeric(4000000))
trees_dt <- as.data.table(trees)

f1 <- function(trees) {
  trees$Heigth_PCT <- round((100 / sum(trees$Height) * trees$Height), digits = 2)
  return(trees)
}

f2 <- function(trees) {
  sum_trees <- sum(trees$Height)
  trees$Heigth_PCT <- round((100 / sum_trees * trees$Height), digits = 2)
  return(trees)
}

f3 <- function(trees) {
  trees$Heigth_PCT <- round(prop.table(trees$Height)*100, digits = 2)
  return(trees)
}

f4 <- function(trees_dt) {
  trees_dt[, Heigth_PCT := round(prop.table(Height)*100, 2)] 
}

# Time both functions
microbenchmark(r1 <- f1(trees),
               r2 <- f2(trees),
               r3 <- f3(trees),
               r4 <- f4(trees_dt),
               times = 100)
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#    r1 <- f1(trees) 296.4452 309.3853 373.5945 318.7987 400.0373 639.8556   100   a
#    r2 <- f2(trees) 296.3453 310.6638 381.4048 323.0655 474.9295 682.2172   100   a
#    r3 <- f3(trees) 304.3185 317.0654 383.9600 328.5494 395.6238 783.2435   100   a
# r4 <- f4(trees_dt) 304.3327 315.4685 361.9526 325.8711 366.1153 722.7629   100   a

sapply(list(r2, r3, as.data.frame(r4)), identical, r1)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

#### Edit: `prop.table()` added.

#### Edit 2: `data.table()` added.

Answer (score 0):

Converting first to `data.table` and then using `prop.table` is a bit faster then `f1`-`f3` (IF you neglect the conversion to a `data.table`, as this is usually only done once for all subsequent commands).

```
# Get data
data(trees)    

# Load package & convert to data.table
library(data.table)
trees <- as.data.table(trees)

# data.table way to create the new variable
f4 <- function(trees) {
  trees[, Heigth_percentage:=round(prop.table(Height)*100,2)] 
}
```

Here are the bechmark results:

```
# > microbenchmark(r1 <- f1(trees),
#                  +                r2 <- f2(trees),
#                  +                r3 <- f3(trees),
#                  +                r3 <- f4(trees),
#                  +                times = 10000)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq       max neval cld
# r1 <- f1(trees) 616.616 666.290 730.8883 683.122 708.164  8390.818 10000   b
# r2 <- f2(trees) 617.437 666.701 730.3211 683.533 709.191  8100.574 10000   b
# r3 <- f3(trees) 596.500 655.616 721.1057 672.243 697.080 55048.757 10000   b
# r4 <- f4(trees) 551.342 612.922 680.7581 633.037 665.059 54672.712 10000  a
```

Comment: I am curious why `f3` is slower than `f1` and `f2` in my timings and a bit faster in yours, but that is not very important here.

Comment: Good question. I just copied your code and added `f4`.